# Extract value of string with regexp_substr in Quantun GIS

Tags: regex, substring, gis

I want to extract specific strings out of an semicolon separated text string in Q-Gis.
In Oracle i can use additional parameters with the regexp_substr function to circle through the search patterns but in Q-Gis this option is missing.

Example sting:

```
14;hotel;paris;33
```

Goal:

```
string 1: 14
string 2: hotel
string 3: paris
string 4: 33
```

Which is the best way to get the strings on demand with the regexp_substr function

I have done some tests to separate the string in subpatterns, but i don't know how to point to them separately.

```
(\d+);(\w+);(\w+);(\d+)
```

examples:

> ```
> regexp_substr("14;hotel;paris;33" ,'([^;0-9]+)')
> ```

This will extract the substring "hotel", but how could I get the location string "paris"?

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](https://github.com/rldhont/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/resources/function_help/regexp_substr) :

```
Backslash characters must be double escaped (eg "\\s" to match a white space character)
```

So you should use `(\\d+);(\\w+);(\\w+);(\\d+)`

Comment: but how can i separate the string part "paris" with the regexp_substr function? Which is the best way to iterate through a delimited string?